# Simulating a Moving Average Process

Tags: python, simulation

I was studying stochastic processes and thought to independently simulate a moving average process.

```
# SIMULATING A MOVING AVERAGE PROCESS of order 10
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

error_list = [random.normalvariate(0, 1) for _ in range(5011)]
ma_process = []

coefficients = [random.randint(-5, 5) for _ in range(11)]
for i in range(10, 5011):
    s = 0
    for j in range(i-10, i):
        # s += error_list[j] # this is for the coefficients all equaling 1
        s += error_list[j] * coefficients[i - j] # coefficients all not 1
    ma_process.append(s)

print(sum(ma_process)/len(ma_process))
plt.plot(ma_process)
plt.axhline(y=0, color='red') # expected value of mean is 0
plt.show()
```

The print statement is basically to compare the actual value of sample mean with the expected value of 0.

I'd like to know whether I can improve my code using any best practices I may have skipped. I am new to this site but not SE in general, so I have tried to adhere to all the guidelines to asking a good question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, if you downvote please tell me the reason, so I can improve the post! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## docstring

```
# SIMULATING A MOVING AVERAGE PROCESS of order 10
```

That `# comment` looks to me like it wants to be a module-level """docstring""".

But then as we read a bit more,
it looks like most of the module's code
wants to be moved into a `def` function.

---

## cite your reference

A moving average process is a well known concept.
But when you cite a particular author,
that gives us more context about the assumptions you're making
and the problem you're trying to solve.
It admits of more mechanical checking for correctness,
by simply drawing a correspondence between the cited work and the source code.

Here, you didn't cite anything, leaving us with the default choice of
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model).
But if that was your reference, then instead of `coefficients`
the more natural identifier choice would have been `theta`,
so perhaps you had another author in mind.

---

## DRY, magic

```
error_list = [... for _ in range(5011)]
...
coefficients = [... for _ in range(11)]
for i in range(10, 5011):
    ...
    for j in range(i - 10, i):
```

Oh, my goodness, so many anonymous
[magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
numbers, some of them
[repeated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
You have passed up the opportunity to give them explanatory names.
Some of them appear to be related to each other,
in an off-by-one way, but you're not helping the Gentle Reader
to understand those relationships.

This code is crying out to be packaged up as a function.
And then we could give it keyword-default parameters
of ten or five thousand or whatever.

The function should `return ma_process`.

---

## commented code

Commented code serves a purpose during the edit-debug development cycle,
but we remove it prior to requesting PR review, since it shouldn't
be merged down to `main`.

```
        # s += error_list[j] # this is for the coefficients all equaling 1
        s += error_list[j] * coefficients[i - j] # coefficients all not 1
```

It's unclear what advice you are trying to offer.

If this loop has two operating modes,
then offer a `bool` parameter which defaults to `False`,
and let the other line of code execute when we've requested the other mode.

---

## output

We see some printing and plotting, once `ma_process` is available.
Package them up in a separate function.
This will e.g. allow a
[unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
to evaluate `ma_process` figures without producing any chatty output.

---

This code appears to achieve some of its design goals.

I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it
in its current form.

Comment: Wow, this is certainly a huge amount improvement I need to do! I, being a beginner, foolishly believed it to be somewhat good code, but have learnt so much through this answer, especially stuff like magic numbers. Thanks a lot